# "Healthy" vs "healthful"— Do fruits and veggies work out?

Tags: etymology, phrases, word-usage

The OED doesn't say much other than the two words have long been synonyms since the 1500s.

> *healthful* - promoting good health
>
> *healthy* - being in good health/condition

Why do we say that our bananas and tomatoes are *healthy* foods when it should be *healthful*?

Is there any substantial evidence on why this widely used terminology is bungled?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its statement that healthy cannot mean healthful is a rant.

Answer (score 2):

Actually their use as synonyms appears to be still an issue:

Usage Note: The distinction in meaning between healthy ("possessing good health") and healthful ("conducive to good health") was ascribed to the two terms only as late as the 1880s. This distinction, though tenaciously supported by some critics, is belied by citational evidence—healthy has been used to mean "healthful" since the 16th century. Use of healthy in this sense is to be found in the works of many distinguished writers, with this example from John Locke being typical: "Gardening . . . and working in wood, are fit and healthy recreations for a man of study or business." **Therefore, both healthy and healthful are correct in these contexts: a healthy climate, a healthful climate; a healthful diet, a healthy diet.**

Source: The American Heritage Dict.

Comment: This is a bit of circular reasoning... so then why did John Locke use the term healthy instead of healthful?

Comment: I agree, it appears that their use as synonyms is not resolved yet.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd because Locke wanted to, and there's nothing that prescriptivists such as yourself can do to stop such usage .

Answer (score 1):

Merriam Webster gives three meanings for Healthy:

> 1. enjoying health and vigor of body, mind, or spirit :  well
> 2. evincing health
> 3. conducive to health

I think the third meaning is the one that overlaps with "healthful."

Answer (score -1):

This answer examines how dictionaries and usage commentators have treated *healthy* and *healthful* (and, crucially, a third word: *wholesome*). My purpose is not to reach some conclusion about the validity of current usage—since usage validates itself—but to trace how views of the three words evolved historically from the era of Samuel Johnson to the present.

---

***'Healthy' and 'healthful' in Merriam-Webster's 'WDEU' and Ayres's 'The Verbalist'***

Here is the first half of the entry for "healthy, healthful" in *Webster's Dictionary of English Usage* (1989):

> **healthy, healthful** In the *Saturday Review* of 17 Mar. 1979 Thomas H. Middleton wrote, "The sad truth is that *healthy* has so often been used to mean 'healthful' that any dictionary worth its flyleaf just has to list 'healthful' as one of *healthy*'s meanings." This and a notice in a column by James J. Kilpatrick (28 June 1985) attest to the flourishing condition of the old issue of the distinction between *healthful* and *healthy*. Here is the gist of the prescription: *healthful* means "conducive to health" (it does) and *healthy* means "enjoying or evincing health" (it does), and never the twain shall meet. The trouble is that *healthy* is used for the sense of *healthful* just given. How long has this sloppy confusion of distinct words been going on? Since the middle of the 16th century—in other words, for more than 400 years.
>
> The distinction itself was invented by Alfred Ayres only in 1881 [in *The Verbalist*]. It has certainly been repeated many times since, right up into the 1980s. But it should surprise no one that the distinction has often not been observed: there never was a distinction in the first place (unless you count the 150-year head start *healthful* had on *healthy*).

As the header to his discussion makes clear, however, the distinction that Ayres, [*The Verbalist*](https://books.google.com/books?id=fWgPAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22The+Verbalist%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4_bKQw7XXAhVC9GMKHUn3AcEQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=healthful&f=false) (1881) is primarily concerned with is the one between *healthy* and *wholesome*. Indeed, *WDEU*'s failure to address the role of *wholesome* in its analysis of *healthful* and *healthy*—and its failure to look at the meanings of the three terms in reference books from before 1881—calls into doubt its conclusions in the second paragraph quoted above. Here is the relevant entry in *The Verbalist*:

> **Healthy—Wholesome.** The first of these two words is often improperly used for the second ; as, "Onions are a *healthy* vegetable." A man, if he is in good health, is *healthy* ; the food he eats, if it is not deleterious, is *wholesome*. A *healthy* ox makes *wholesome* food. We speak of *healthy* surroundings, a *healthy* climate, situation, employment, and of *wholesome* food, advice, examples. *Healthful* is generally used in the sense of conducive to health, virtue, morality ; as, *healthful* exercise, the *healthful* spirit of the community—meaning that the spirit that prevails in the community is conducive to virtue and good morals.

This is a surprising entry—not least because it presents us not with two words to sort out, but three. Complicating the situation further, Ayres gives his definitions of the three terms rather obliquely. Rereading the paragraph, we find only that *healthy* may mean "in good health," *wholesome* may mean "not deleterious," and *healthful* (more precisely than the other two) "conducive to health, virtue, morality." But it quickly becomes clear that Ayres does not restrict the meaning of *healthy* to "in good health," since he volunteers that surroundings, a climate, a situation, and employment may be healthy, and yet he does not seem inclined to mean thereby that they are in good health.

One thing we can conclude with a fair degree of certainty, however, is that if he were asked whether bananas and tomatoes are healthy foods or healthful foods, Ayres would answer, "Neither. They are wholesome foods."

---

***Distinguishing 'healthful,' 'healthy,' and 'wholesome' through the years***

One striking feature of early definitions of the three words is that the overlap in meaning comes not from expansive use of *healthy* but from expansive use of *healthful* and *wholesome*. Consider the definitions of *healthful*, *healthy*, and *wholesome* in Samuel Johnson, [*A Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=fcVEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT428&f=false#v=onepage&q=%22salutary%20productive%22&f=false) (1756) [wording in square brackets appears only in the unabridged 1755–1756 edition of the dictionary]:

> HEALTHFUL. *a*. {*health* and *full*.} 1. Free from sickness. *South[ey]*. 2. Well disposed. *Shakespeare*. 3. Wholesome; salubrious. *Bacon*. 4. Salutary; productive of salvation. *[Book of] Com[mon] Prayer*.
>
> ...
>
> HEALTHY. *a*. {from *health*.} In health; free from sickness[; hale; sound]. *Arbuthnot*.
>
> ...
>
> WHOLESOME. *adj*. {*heelsam*, Dutch.} 1. Sound. [*Contrary to unsound in doctrine.*] *Shakespeare*. 2. Contributing to health. 3. Preserving; salutary. [Obsolete] *Psalms*. 4. Kindly; pleasing. [*A burlesque use.*] *Shakespeare*.

Johnson also throws in an entry for *healthsome*, which he defines as "Wholesome; salutary." It seems clear from the three definitions above that *healthful* and *wholesome* carried multiple broad, overlapping meanings while *healthy* carried one relatively narrow one.

Jumping ahead half a century to Noah Webster, *A Compendious Dictionary of the English Language* (1806), we find that the definitions of *healthful* remains expansive, the definition of *healthy* remains limited, and the definition of *wholesome* has gotten narrower:

> **Healthful, Healthsome,** *a*. free from sickness, strong, well-disposed, wholesome
>
> ...
>
> **Healthy,** *a*. free from sickness, hale, sound, strong
>
> ...
>
> **Wholesome,** *a*. contributing to health, salutary

Ayres's book came out at a time when the Merriam-Webster's dictionary of record was *An American Dictionary of the English Language* (1864). That dictionary broadens the definition of *healthy* without significantly reducing the reach of the other two:

> **Healthful,** *a.* **1.** Full of health; free from illness or disease; well; entire; sound; healthy; as a *healthful* body, a *healthful* person, a *healthful* plant. **2.** Serving to promote health; wholesome; salubrious; salutary; as a healthful air or climate; a *healthful* diet. **3.** Indicating, characterized by or resulting from, health or soundness, as, a *healthful* condition. **4.** Well-disposed; favorable.
>
> ...
>
> **Healthy,** *a.* **1.** Being in a state of health; enjoying health; hale; sound; as, a healthy body or constitution. **2.** Conducive to health; wholesome; salubrious; as, a healthy exercise; a healthy climate; healthy recreations.
>
> ...
>
> **Wholesome,** *a.* **1.** Tending to promote health; favoring health; salubrious; salutary. [Example:] "*Wholesome* thirst and appetite," *Milton*. **2.** Contributing to the health of the mind; favorable to morals, religion, or prosperity; conducive to good; salutary; sound; as *wholesome* advice; *wholesome* doctrines; *wholesome* truths; *wholesome* laws.

At this point, the overlaps have become quite large and potentially confusing—and this is the background for Ayres's proposal regarding what he takes to be the proper meanings of the different words. Ayers was not, however, the first usage commentator to address the issue. Ten Years before *The Verbalist*, Charles Smith, [*Synonyms Discriminated: A Complete Catalogue of Synonymous Words*](https://books.google.com/books?id=oImx5HFA3FUC&pg=PA374&dq=healthful+wholesome&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW3uzx2LXXAhXKx1QKHapSBgIQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=healthful%20wholesome&f=false) (1871) offered this rather detailed treatment of the three words:

> HEALTHY (A[nglo] S[axon] *häldh*, health) bears the twofold meaning of *possessing* health, and *imparting* health. A healthy person; a healthy atmosphere. WHOLESOME (whole, in the sense of sound) is tending to health or soundness, or not inconsistent with them, whether of mind or body or mind; as a wholesome appetite, wholesome air, wholesome advice. But both healthy and wholesome are commonly employed in in more than a negative sense, as when we say, "the situation is perfectly healthy," "the food is quite wholesome." Healthy or healthful stands to wholesome as the positive to the negative. The former promotes or increases our bodily strength; the latter does no harm to our physical constitution. And so healthy is more commonly applied to what comes to us in the way of exceptional benefit; wholesome, to the necessaries of life. Unwholesome food disorganizes the functions of the body; healthy air and recreation improve the physical powers. In like manner, a wholesome truth, wholesome advice, is preservative of morality and our interests. A healthy tone of mind tends to the improvement of our faculties. The wholesome is assimilated and acted upon *by* us; the healthy acts *upon* us.

Here, as in Ayres, the primary distinction that the author is trying to make is between *healthy* and *wholesome*. But unlike Ayres, Smith finds the primary distinction to lie in the promotional power of the healthy thing as opposed to the more passive utility of the merely wholesome thing.

Smith would agree, I think, with Ayres's assertion that "Onions are a healthy vegetable" is improper usage—because Smith considers food to be at best a passive good. Indeed, Ayres gives a nod to Smith's analytical framework when he says, "the food [a man] eats, if it is not deleterious, is *wholesome*. In both books, *healthful* seems to be unaccountably neglected, considering that its dictionary definitions are the most expansive of the group's.

Decades earlier than the works of either Ayres or Smith are books by two Englishmen—George Crabb and G.F. Graham—that don't mention *healthful* at all. The cited books of both of these authors ran through multiple editions in the United States and were used in U.S. schools for multiple decades. From George Crabb, [*English Synonymes, with Copious Illustrations and Explanations*](https://books.google.com/books?id=E3oSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA545&dq=%22kindly+influence+on+the+bodily+constitution%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie9-yU47XXAhVnqFQKHdWnBEkQ6AEIRzAF#v=onepage&q=%22kindly%20influence%20on%20the%20bodily%20constitution%22&f=false), second edition (1818):

> HEALTHY, WHOLESOME, SALUBRIOUS, SALUTARY.
>
> *HEALTHY* signifies not only having *health*, but also causing *health*, or keeping in *health*.
>
> *WHOLESOME*, like the German *heilsam*, signifies making whole, keeping whole or sound.
>
> ...
>
> These epithets are all applicable to such objects as have a kindly influence on the bodily constitution: *healthy* is the most general and indefinite; it is applied to exercise, to air, situation, climate, and most other things, but food, for which *wholesome* is commonly substituted: the life of a farmer is reckoned the most *healthy*; and the simplest diet is the most *wholesome*. *Healthy* and *wholesome* are rather negative in their sense; *salubrious* and *salutary* are positive: that is *healthy* and *wholesome* which does no injury health; that is *salubrious* which serves to improve the health; and that is *salutary* which serves to remove a disorder: climates are *healthy* or *unhealthy*, according to the constitution of the person; water is a *wholesome* beverage for those who are not dropsical; bread is a *wholesome* diet for human beings; ...

From G.F. Graham, [*English Synonymes Classified and Explained; with Practical Exercises, Designed for Schools and Private Tuition*](https://books.google.com/books?id=33g-AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA179&dq=%22healthy+which+promotes+or+increases+our+bodily+strength%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk1Y6-5rXXAhUS-GMKHdK5AWIQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22healthy%20which%20promotes%20or%20increases%20our%20bodily%20strength%22&f=false) (1846):

> *Healthy — Wholesome*.
>
> That is *healthy* which promotes or increases our bodily strength. That is *wholesome* which does no harm to our physical constitution, but possesses the quality of health. Pure air, exercise, occupations, &c., are healthy; plain food, diet, &c., are wholesome. The internal functions of the body are disorganized by unwholesome food; the physical powers of the body are disorganized by unwholesome food; the physical powers are improved by healthy air and regular exercise. In like manner, abstractly, a wholesome doctrine is a preservative to our morality; a healthy tone of mind tends to the improvement of out faculties. What is healthy acts upon us; what is wholesome, we act upon.

It's fairly clear that Smith took his cues from Graham, who in turn was beholden to Crabb. The main change between Graham and Crabb is that Crabb drops *salubrious* and *salutary* from consideration and adjusts his interpretation of the negative and positive aspects of *wholesome* and *healthy* so that *healthy* fills the void in positivity left by the departure of *salubrious* and *salutary*. The main innovation of Smith was to bring *healthful* into the picture after Crabb and Graham ignored it. However, Smith merely mentions *healthful* in passing as if it were interchangeable in meaning with *healthy*.

So on the one hand, Ayres is the first synonym commentator to insist on distinctions between *healthful* and *healthy* (although dictionaries had been identifying such distinctions for more than a hundred years), but on the other synonym commentators had been asserting differences in the objects of *healthy* and *wholesome* since at least 1818. And in the post-Ayres era, *healthful* acquired some of the old applications—most notably to foods—that commentators had formerly assigned to *wholesome* and withheld from *healthy*.

John Bechtel, [*Slips of Speech: A Helpful Book for Everyone who Aspires to Correct the Everyday Errors of speaking and Writing*](https://books.google.com/books?id=KolOAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA100&dq=%22Slips+of+Speech%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mq64VJfdKJbboAS06YHICw&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=wholesome&f=false) (1895) takes the crucial step of separating his discussion of *healthy* and *healthful* from his discussion of *healthy* and *wholesome*:

> **Healthy, Wholesome**
>
> These terms are not synonymous. Toadstools may be *healthy*, but they would not be regarded as *wholesome*. Plants and animals are *healthy* when the conditions of their growth are favorable. They are *wholesome* when, as food, they promote the health of those persons who eat them.
>
> ...
>
> **Healthy, Healthful**
>
> A lady wrote to a paper asking, "Are plants in a sleeping-room *unhealthy*?" The answer came, "Not necessarily; we have seen some very *healthy* plants growing in sleeping-rooms."
>
> Persons are *healthy* or *unhealthy*. A plant or tree is *healthy* or *unhealthy* according as it possesses vigor. Food, surroundings and conditions are *healthful* or *unhealthful* according as they promote or destroy health.

It remains for Frank Vizetelly, [*A Desk-Book of Errors in English: Including Notes on Colloquialisms and Slang to Be Avoided in Conversation*](https://books.google.com/books?id=YrIaAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA178&dq=%22proven+an+irregular+form%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tkNYVJv2JYvnoATrg4HYAg#v=onepage&q=healthful&f=false) (1908) to complete the swing of attention toward *healthy* versus *healthful* by omitting any mention of *wholesome*:

> **healthful, healthy :** Discriminate carefully between these words. A *healthful* thing is one efficacious in promoting or causing health; *healthy* denotes condition or characteristics; as "a *healthy* child"' "a *healthy* climate."

---

***Conclusions: 'healthful' and 'healthy' today***

The absence of *wholesome* from the discussion over the past century is quite remarkable. For example, Bryan Garner, [*Garner's Modern American Usage*](https://books.google.com/books?id=FwmQpyibKkAC&pg=PA575&dq=%22notwithstanding+is+a+FORMAL+WORD%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rA0mVeWRF8b7oQSJ2oHACA&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=healthful%20healthy&f=false), third edition (2009) addresses only *healthy* and *healthful*:

> **healthful; healthy.** Strictly speaking, *healthy* refers to a person or personified thing) in good health, *healthful* to whatever promotes good health. E.g.: "Low-fat dairy products ... will keep us feeling *healthy* and good about ourselves, she says. A vegetarian, Barnes takes *healthful* dishes to parties." [Citation omitted.] In fact, though, many writers use *healthy* when they mean *healthful*, and *healthy* threatens to edge out its sibling. Such a development would be unhealthful, since it would lead to a less healthy state of the language. LANGUAGE-CHANGE INDEX *healthy* for *healthful*: Stage 4 [At this stage, the new form "becomes virtually universal but is opposed on cogent grounds by a few linguistic stalwarts (die-hard snoots)."]

It seems evident that usage commentators today have shifted the qualities that formerly distinguished *wholesome* from *healthy* to the word *healthful*. The most stubborn holdout in the general movement toward replacing *healthful* with *healthy* is food-related usage—and this makes sense historically. From the eighteenth century, when *healthful* had a considerably broader range of meanings than *healthy* did, through the middle and late nineteenth century, when *healthy* and *healthful* had a great deal of overlap, the one category that authorities continuously excluded from the proper reach of *healthy* was foods.

For many decades, dictionaries and usage commentators have endorsed the idea that  bananas and tomatoes may be termed *wholesome* or *healthful*. But only in recent years, and even then rather obliquely, have they approved of calling fruits and vegetables *healthy*.

---

***Postscript: Webster's Collegiate Dictionaries on 'healthful" versus 'healthy'***

For 33 years—from 1916 through 1948—editions of the *Webster's Collegiate Dictionary* series included the following usage note explicitly addressing the difference between *healthful* and *healthy*:

> **Healthy** and **healthful** are interchangeable within certain limits. But *healthy* oftener applies to that which is in a state of health or vigor ; as, a *healthy* (not *healthful*) man ; *healthful* (not *healthy*) food ; a *healthful* (or *healthy*) climate.

The *Sixth Collegiate* (1949), however, dropped any discussion of *healthful* from a usage note under the entry for *healthy* that compared the words *healthy*, *sound*, *wholesome*, *robust*, *hale*, and *well*—all of which "mean enjoying or indicative of good health." That note remains unchanged 68 years later, although for unknown reasons it was dropped from the *Eighth Collegiate* (1973).

For the *Ninth Collegiate* (1983), Merriam-Webster restored the usage note under *healthy*—and even more surprisingly, it added a new usage note under the entry for *healthful*, comparing that word to *wholesome*, *salubrious*, and *salutary*—a group whose members "mean favorable to the health of mind or body." This results in an odd relationship among the old threesome of *healthful*, *healthy*, and *wholesome*. The *Ninth Collegiate* (and the *Tenth* [1993] and the *Eleventh* [2003]) details how the modern meanings of *healthful* and *wholesome* differ:

> HEALTHY implies full strength and vigor as well as freedom from signs of disease {a *healthy* family}. ... WHOLESOME implies appearance and behavior indicating soundness and balance {a face with a *wholesome* glow.}

and how the modern senses of *healthy* and *wholesome* differ:

> HEALTHFUL implies a positive contribution to a healthy condition {a *healthful* diet}. WHOLESOME applies to what benefits, builds up, or sustains physically, mentally, or spiritually {*wholesome* foods} {the movie is *wholesome* family entertainment}.

But in the past six editions of its Collegiate Dictionary series, Merriam-Webster has avoided directly comparing *healthful* and *healthy* and discussing how they differ in current usage.

---

**Update (August 17, 2021)**

I ran searches of Early English Books On line (a database of texts published from 1450 to 1700) for instances of "healthy climate," "healthful climate," "wholesome climate," "healthy food," "healthful food" and "wholesome food"—all instances in which the word *healthy*, *healthful*, or *wholesome* carries the meaning "conducive to health." Here are the results:

> **healthy climate:** four matches (from 1685, 1689, 1691, and 1693)
>
> **healthful climate:** eight matches (from 1662, 1671, 1682, 1692, 1694, 1695, 1696, and 1700)
>
> **wholesome climate:** three matches (from 1622, 1635, and 1651)
>
> **healthy food:** nine matches (from 1677, 1682, 1691, 1692, 1694, 1694, 1695, 1695, and 1696)
>
> **healthful food:** thirteen matches (from 1657, 1657, 1658, 1660, 1661, 1664, 1668, 1670, 1674, 1677, 1678, 1695, and 1700)
>
> **wholesome food:** 291 matches (from 1593, 1597, 1600, 1603, 1605, 1606, 1608, 1609, ...)

These results suggest that *wholesome* in the sense of "conducive to health" was in widespread use about half a century earlier than *healthful* (in the same sense), with *healthy* (also in the same sense) joining the fray a couple of decades after that.